# fixing the code in python to change a text file

Tags: python

I have a big text file like the small example:

small example:

```
chr1    37091   37122   D00645:305:CCVLRANXX:1:1104:21074:48301 0   -
chr1    37091   37122   D00645:305:CCVLRANXX:1:1104:4580:50451  0   -
chr1    37091   37122   D00645:305:CCVLRANXX:1:1106:13064:5974  0   -
chr1    37091   37122   D00645:305:CCVLRANXX:1:1106:16735:48726 0   -
chr1    37091   37122   D00645:305:CCVLRANXX:1:2210:5043:83540  0   -
chr1    37091   37122   D00645:305:CCVLRANXX:1:2204:15744:24410 0   -
chr1    37091   37122   D00645:305:CCVLRANXX:1:2204:19627:73060 0   -
chr1    37091   37122   D00645:305:CCVLRANXX:1:2206:8497:68295  0   -
chr1    37091   37122   D00645:305:CCVLRANXX:1:1312:11371:24672 0   -
chr1    37091   37122   D00645:305:CCVLRANXX:1:1312:17050:42431 0   -
chr1    37091   37122   D00645:305:CCVLRANXX:1:1312:12969:62696 0   -
chr1    37091   37122   D00645:305:CCVLRANXX:1:1312:6478:73521  0   -
chr1    37091   37122   D00645:305:CCVLRANXX:1:1312:8402:80222  0   -
chr1    37091   37122   D00645:305:CCVLRANXX:1:1309:19837:15007 0   -
chr1    37091   37122   D00645:305:CCVLRANXX:1:1309:20126:89687 0   -
chr1    37091   37122   D00645:305:CCVLRANXX:1:1310:2838:27860  0   -
chr1    37091   37122   D00645:305:CCVLRANXX:1:1310:7280:85906  0   -
chr1    54832   54863   D00645:305:CCVLRANXX:1:2102:19886:3949  0   -
chr1    74307   74338   D00645:305:CCVLRANXX:1:2203:13233:29983 0   -
chr1    74325   74356   D00645:305:CCVLRANXX:1:1310:7266:92995  0   -
chr1    93529   93560   D00645:305:CCVLRANXX:1:1103:1743:29602  0   +
chr1    93529   93560   D00645:305:CCVLRANXX:1:1101:16098:97354 0   +
```

I am trying to count the lines with similar 1st, 2nd and 3rd columns and make a new file with 4 columns in which the first 3 columns are similar to the original file but the 4th column is number of times that every row is repeated. for example there `17` rows with  `chr1 37091   37122`
here is the expected output for the above small example:

expected output:

```
chr1    37091   37122   17
chr1    54832   54863   1
chr1    74307   74338   1
chr1    74325   74356   1
chr1    93529   93560   2
```

I wrote this code in python but it does not return what I want. do you how to fix it?

```
infile = open('infile.txt', 'rb')
content = []
for i in infile:
    content.append(i.split())

final = []
for j in range(len(content)):
    if content[j] == content[j-1]:
        final.append(content[j])

with open('outfile.txt','w') as f:
    for sublist in final:
        for item in sublist:
            f.write(item + '\t')
        f.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Counter` like this:

```
from collections import Counter

infile = open('infile.txt', 'rb')
content = []
for i in infile:
    # append only first 3 columns as one line string
    content.append('  '.join(i.split()[:3]))

# this is now dictionary
c = Counter(content)


elements = c.most_common(len(c.elements()))

with open('outfile.txt','w') as f:
    for item, freq in elements:
        f.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(item, freq))
```

Comment: this line gives error: elements = c.most_common(len(c.elements()))

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `pandas` and your solution will be really easy:

Just read the big txt file in a pandas `dataframe` like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('infile.txt', sep=' ')
df.groupby([0,1,2]).count()
```

This should give you:

```
chr1 37091 37122     17
     74325 74356      1
     93529 93560      2
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular dictionary with your target comparison lines as keys:

```
infile = 'infile.txt'
content = {}

with open(infile, 'r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        temp = line.split()
        if not temp[1]+temp[2] in content:
            content[temp[1]+temp[2]] = [1, temp[0:3]]
        else:
            content[temp[1]+temp[2]][0]+=1

with open('outfile.txt','w') as fout:
    for key, value in content.items():
        for entry in value[1]:
            fout.write(entry + ' ')
        fout.write(str(value[0]) + '\n')
```

The key is a concatenated second and third column. The value is a list - first element is the counter and second element is a list of values from your input file you want to save to the output. The if checks if there is already an entry with given key - if yes, it increments the counter, if not - it creates a new list with counter set to 1 and the appropriate values as the list part.

Note that for consistency the program uses the recommended `with open` in both cases. It also doesn't read the txt file in binary mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
with open('infile.txt', 'r') as file:
    content = [i.split() for i in file.readlines()]

results = {}
for i in data:
    # use .setdefault to set counter as 0, increment at each match.
    results.setdefault('\t'.join(i[:3]), 0)
    results['\t'.join(i[:3])] += 1

# results

# {'chr1\t37091\t37122': 17, 
#  'chr1\t54832\t54863': 1, 
#  'chr1\t74307\t74338': 1,
#  'chr1\t74325\t74356': 1, 
#  'chr1\t93529\t93560': 2}

# Output the results with list comprehension
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines('\t'.join((k, str(v))) for k, v in results.items())
```

---

Or, just use `Counter`:

```
import Counter
with open('infile.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = ['\t'.join(i.split()[:3]) for i in file.readlines()]

with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines('\t'.join((k, str(v))) for k, v in Counter(data).items())

# Counter(data).items()

# dict_items([('chr1\t37091\t37122', 17),
#             ('chr1\t54832\t54863', 1), 
#             ('chr1\t74307\t74338', 1), 
#             ('chr1\t74325\t74356', 1),
#             ('chr1\t93529\t93560', 2)])
```

---

In either case we group the first three "columns" as a key, then use said key to identify the number of times it occured in your data.