# summarizing 2 text files into one file in python

Tags: python

I have 2 files called `big` and `small` like these examples:

`big`:

```
chr1    transcript      2481359 2483515 -       RP3-395M20.8
chr1    transcript      2487078 2492123 +       TNFRSF14
chr1    transcript      2497849 2501297 +       RP3-395M20.7
chr1    transcript      2512999 2515942 +       RP3-395M20.9
chr1    transcript      2517930 2521041 +       FAM213B
chr1    transcript      2522078 2524087 -       MMEL1
```

`small`:

```
chr1    2487088 2492113 17
chr1    100757323       100757324       19
chr1    2487099 2492023 21
chr1    100758316       100758317       41
chr1    2514000 2515742 14
```

I trying to make a new file with `5 columns` from big file upon the
following conditions:

`conditions` :

```
1- if: the 1st column of small file == 1st column of big file
2- if: the 4th column of big file >= the 2nd column of small file >= the 3rd column of big file
3- if: the 4th column of big file >= the 3rd column of small file >= the 3rd column of big file
```

`columns in output file`:

```
1) 1st column of big file
2) 2nd column of big file
3) 3rd column of big file
4) the number of lines in small files that have the mentioned conditions (we should count)
5) 6th column of big file
```

here is the expected output for the above example:

```
chr1    2487078 2492123 2       TNFRSF14
chr1    2512999 2515942 1       RP3-395M20.9
```

I wrote the following code in `python`. it does not return the file that
I want. every line in my code seems to be logical. would you help my
to fix it?

```
def correspond(big, small, outfile):
    count = 0
    big = open(big, "r")
    small = open(small, "r")
    big_list = []
    small_list = []
    for m in big:
        big_list.append(m)
    for n in small:
        small_list.append(n)
    final = []
    for i in range(0, len(small_list)):
        for j in range(0, len(big_list)):
            small_row = small_list[i]
            big_row = big_list[j]
            small_columns = small_row.split()
            big_columns = big_row.split()
            small_symbol = small_columns[0]
            big_symbol = big_columns[0]
            name = big_columns[5]
            if small_symbol == big_symbol:
                small_second_col = small_columns[1]
                small_third_col = small_columns[2]
                min_range = big_columns[2]
                max_range = big_columns[3]
                if (small_second_col <= max_range and small_second_col >= min_range and small_third_col <= max_range and small_third_col >= min_range):
                        count+=1
                        new_line = small_row.rstrip("\n") + " " + big_symbol + " " + min_range + " " + max_range + str(count) + name
                        final.append(new_line)
    with open(outfile, "w") as f:
        for item in final:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: Can you use pandas? this would be very easy with pandas

Comment: Surprisingly like earlier questions this week (!), such as https://stackoverflow.com/q/53174083/2564301. Are y'all in the same class?

Comment: Learn bedtools or pybedtools. You're trying to do an intersection of .bed files, and that's why (py)bedtools was developed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998160/summarizing-2-text-files-in-python/52998780#52998780

Answer (score 1):

Full working solution, no pandas:

```
from itertools import product


def str_or_int(item):
    try:
        return int(item)
    except ValueError:
        return item

def correspond(big, small, output):
    with open(big, 'r') as bigf, open(small, 'r') as smallf, open(output, 'w') as outputf:
        current = None
        count = 0
        for b_line, s_line in product(filter(lambda x: x != '\n', bigf), filter(lambda x: x != '\n', smallf)):
            if b_line != current:
                if count > 0:
                    out_line = current.split()
                    outputf.write('\t'.join((out_line[0], out_line[1], out_line[2], str(count), out_line[5])) + '\n')
                current = b_line
                count = 0
            b_line = [str_or_int(s) for s in b_line.split()]
            s_line = [str_or_int(s) for s in s_line.split()]
            try:
                if b_line[0] == s_line[0] and b_line[3] >= s_line[1] >= b_line[2] and b_line[3] >= s_line[2] >= b_line[2]:
                    count += 1
            except IndexError:
                continue
```

Ask in comments if you have questions

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample input like this:

```
big = '''chr1    transcript      2481359 2483515 -       RP3-395M20.8
chr1    transcript      2487078 2492123 +       TNFRSF14
chr1    transcript      2497849 2501297 +       RP3-395M20.7
chr1    transcript      2512999 2515942 +       RP3-395M20.9
chr1    transcript      2517930 2521041 +       FAM213B
chr1    transcript      2522078 2524087 -       MMEL1'''

small = '''chr1    2487088 2492113 17
chr1    100757323       100757324       19
chr1    2487099 2492023 21
chr1    100758316       100758317       41
chr1    2514000 2515742 14'''

big, small = ([l.split() for l in d.splitlines()] for d in (big, small))
```

You can use `sum` with a generator expression to count the number of lines in `small` matching the criteria, and then use `str.join` to produce your desired output:

```
for name_big, _, low, high, _, note in big:
    count = sum(1 for name_small, n1, n2, _ in small if name_big == name_small and all(int(low) <= int(n) <= int(high) for n in (n1, n2)))
    if count:
        print('\t'.join((name_big, low, high, str(count), note)))
```

This outputs:

```
chr1    2487078 2492123 2   TNFRSF14
chr1    2512999 2515942 1   RP3-395M20.9
```